# Creating a Regex Pattern to Extract Floats and Integers

Tags: python, regex, for-loop, search

I am having an issue in creating a pattern recognition function to extract all the numbers from a data frame column and print them.

I have tried to create a regex pattern after looking at the data camp tutorial and the other questions on stack overflow, but I have not been able to create a pattern that will extract all the numbers and print them. Essentially, the EA patterns that I created and the HR patterns with floats like say 1.12 are not returning results.

```
import re
import pandas as pd
data = ['1EA @ 3217.45;', 'ST - .63HR@165;', 'ST - .5HR@123;', 'ST - 1.08HR@165;', '1EA @ 3217.45;', 'ST - .85HR@165;', 'ST - .85HR@165;', '1EA @ 3217.45;', 'ST - .12HR@165;', 'OT - 1.12HR @ 165;', 'ST - .55HR@123;OT - 0.82HR @ 123;', 'ST - .5HR@165;', 'OT - 0.45HR @ 123;', 'ST - .6HR@123;', 'ST - 1.42HR@123;', '1EA @ 1500;', 'ST - .3HR@123;', 'ST - 1HR@111;OT - 0.25HR @ 111;']
Travel = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Rate Breakup Description'])

for a in Travel['Rate Breakup Description']:
    print(re.search('.(\d+)HR | (\d+)EA | (\d+)HR | (\d+)EA', a, re.I|re.M))
```

My objective is to be able to have a pattern recognition function that will extract all the numbers regardless of the different string patterns and print them in the order they appear.

Comment: `d` matches `d` and `\d` matches a digit.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Okay, I fixed that in my code. However, when I tried it in Python it still did not return any results for the specified patterns.

Comment: Try `Travel['Rate Breakup Description'].str.findall(r'\d*\.?\d+(?=HR|EA)').apply(', '.join)`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew I got this error when I applied it to the for loop and when I tried to print it all together AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'join'

Comment: Try `.apply(', '.join)`. It is there just in case you have more than 1 match in an input string.  If there is only 1 match per string, use `Travel['Result'] = Travel['Rate Breakup Description'].str.extract(r'(\d*\.?\d+)(?:HR|EA)', expand=False)`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew Looks like this works. Thank you very much. I am not sure why someone down-voted the question, because I did my best to follow all of the guidelines and make everything reproducible. Is there any way that I can prevent this from happening in the future?

Comment: So, the findall version works for you, right? Do not pay attention at downvotes. If your question is written well, you will get upvotes, and if it is interesting, you will get more than 1. Down- and upvoting is subjective here, you can't please everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
Travel['Result'] = Travel['Rate Breakup Description'].str.findall(r'\d*\.?\d+(?=HR|EA)').apply(', '.join)
```

The pattern will match

- `\d*` - 0+ digits
- `\.?` - an optional `.`
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?=HR|EA)` - followed with `HR` or `EA`.

The `.str.findall` will return all matches it finds in an input string, and `.apply(', '.join)`  will join the results with a comma+space.

If there is a single match expected in each input, you might use an alternative solution:

```
Travel['Result'] = Travel['Rate Breakup Description'].str.extract(r'(\d*\.?\d+)(?:HR|EA)', expand=False)
```

Here, `(\d*\.?\d+)` is a capturing group due to the parentheses, this part is returned by `.str.extract` and `(?:HR|EA)` is a non-capturing group (so that it is not returned) matching either `HR` or `EA`.